# CreateThread() passing struct arguments weirdly

Tags: c, windows

I'm passing a `struct` to `CreateThread()` function. The same code on another machine works fine. But on my machine, "`SendItem`" always becomes `0xccccccc Bad Ptr>`.  Does anyone know why?

```
....
myStruct mystruct; 
CreateThread(NULL, 0,  (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)SendItem,(LPVOID)&mystruct, 0, &thread);
...

DWORD WINAPI SendItem(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    myStruct* SendItem= (myStruct*) lpParam;
    ...
}

struct myStruct
{
    char Name [256];
    int ID;
};
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
....
myStruct mystruct; 
CreateThread(NULL, 0,  (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)SendItem,(LPVOID)&mystruct, 0, &thread);
...
```

You're not showing the actual code, but this is presumably in a function somewhere.

You're passing the address of a *local variable* to your thread function. The problem is, that local variable is destroyed as soon as the containing function returns.

The solution is to allocate the object on the heap:

```
void start_thread(void)
{
    myStruct *mystruct = malloc(sizeof(*mystruct));
    if (!mystruct)
        return;

    CreateThread(NULL, 0,  (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)SendItem, (LPVOID)mystruct, 0, &thread);
}
```

Comment: Isn't  the third argument of CreateThread() a function? In my case, `SendItem` is actually `DWORD WINAPI SendItem(LPVOID lpParam)` and `(LPVOID)&mystruct ` is the argument of `SendItem()`

Comment: @MinKim This is why you post *full* examples, not little snippets which can't be compiled.

Comment: I got  error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'mystruct*'

Comment: Full examples are too long... I use `myStruct mystruct; ` to declare mystruct and the full code is compiled ok, but `myStruct *mystruct = malloc(sizeof(*mystruct));` gets an error C2440

Comment: @MinKim You need to escape `*` characters as `\*` to show correctly outside code blocks. The C2440 error is `cannot convert from 'void *' to 'mystruct *'`. Are you compiling the code as C or C++? In C++ you need to cast the return of malloc (void \*) to your type (mystruct \*).

Comment: @MinKim No, that's why you create a *minimal*, *complete* example. Learn to code in smaller units. Since your question is about C, rename your file to .c instead of .cpp so VS compiles it as C code.

Comment: I'm writing C code in .cpp and compile as C++. All files in this project are .cpp  I don't want only one .c mixed with other .cpp. I tried `myStruct ms= (myStruct *)malloc(sizeof(ms));` But still gets  `error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'myStruct *' to 'myStruct ' `  Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Also, *"I'm writing C code in .cpp and compile as C++"* This is not a thing. If you're writing C code, write C code. If you're writing C++ code, write C++ code.

Comment: Sorry, I changed some of my other code and now it works perfectly! Thank you so much!